# Changing PHP code. Calendar event data is not produced correctly

Tags: php, json, pdo, fullcalendar

I am trying to incude my calendar event data in my website (I'm using fullCalendar in the front end) but in these files I used PDO connection, and now I have difficulties with using a replacement function.

Here is my loading code for fetching the calendar events

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fim', 'root', '');
 
$data = array();
 
$query = "SELECT * FROM appointment ORDER BY id";
 
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 
$statement->execute();
 
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
 
foreach($result as $row)
{    
 $data[] = array(
  'id'      => $row["id"],
  'title'   => $row["appointment_client"],
  'start'   => $row["appointment_start"],
  'end'     => $row["appointment_end"]
 );
}
 
echo json_encode($data);
```

And also the new version:

```
$events = Event::find_by_order();
 
$data = array();     
 
foreach($events as $event) {
 
        $data[] = array(
            'id'      => $event->id,
            'title'   => $event->title,
            'start'   => $event->start_event,
            'end'     => $event->end_event 
        );
}
 
echo json_encode($data);
```

When I use the new code I am not getting any output in my calendar.

Also, when I echo the array I get the same result from the both codes.

Comment: This has pretty much nothing to do with fullCalendar. The issue seems to be entirely related to your server side PHP code (fullCalendar is a client side JavaScript application). I'll change the question tags for you. Also both your code examples use OOP (object oriented programming), neither of them uses procedural functions. I've re-worded the question to use better terminology

Comment: Anyway... `when I echo the array I get the same result from the both codes`...if that was really true then the calendar would behave the same as well - unless you've changed something in the rest of the calendar code, unrelated to the code you've shown above? If both those pieces of code produce an identical JSON output then they can't be the source of the issue. So either that statement isn't accurate, or you need to look elsewhere for whatever your issue is.